# RadioButton are coming one on other(coming in one space)

Tags: reactjs, radio-button, radio-group, form-control

I'm using FormControl to implement RadioGroup, it is working fine in Sandbox, but not running fine in my system. It is showing all RadioButtons one on another. Please Help

```
<FormControl>
    <RadioGroup>
      <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
      <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
      <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
    </RadioGroup>
  </FormControl>
```

Comment: Could you please add import/require section from your component?

Comment: import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';                               
Yes, I have already added that, But still not working

Comment: Yes, yes - I just wanted to see the import section :) If it works in isolation, it means that you have CSS styles that potentially break it. Try to use DevTools and focus on particular radio button (or its container) and investigate if any other CSS style is not applied. I have a feeling that there might be some external styles that apply on `input` directly. It's just a guess.